# Decomposition of Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{sl}(V)$ into eigenspaces wrt $Ad(r) \in Aut(\mathfrak{g})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is essentially part of a proof, i´m trying to understand now. So i will give a short summary of the setup. We have $G \subset SL(V)$ algebraic, connected and acting irreducible on $V$. Also let $r \in GL(V)$ be a reflection with special eigenvalue $c \in \mathbb{C}^*$, which normalizes $G$. Then we have that, the Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ is semisimple and irreducible on $V$. Let $Ad(r)$ be the automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$ induced from conjugation by $r$ and consider the eigenspaces $\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda}$ of $Ad(r)$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

---

**Then i want to show, that for $c \neq \pm 1$, $\mathfrak{g}$ decomposes as $$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_c \oplus \mathfrak{g}_{c^{-1}}$$**

---

**Idea:**

We have $Ad(r) \in Aut(\mathfrak {g})$, defined by $Ad(r)(X)=rXr^{-1}$. And note, that $r$ is a reflection, hence has $n-1$ times eigenvalue $1$ and the special eigenvalue $c$. To show: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Ad(r)$, then $\lambda \in \{1,c,c^{-1}\}$:

Suppose $r$ is diagonalizable with diagonal entries $a_1,...,a_n$. Then $Ad(r)$ multiplies the $ij$ entry of a matrix $X$ by $a_i^{-1}a_j$ (since left multiplication by $r$ multiplies the $j$-th column by $a_j$ and right multiplication by $r^{-1}$ multiplies the $i$-th row by $a_i^{-1}$). In other words, with respect to a basis basis on $\mathfrak{g}$, $Ad(r)$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $a_i^{-1}a_j$.

Thus, if $r$ is a diagonalizable matrix, the eigenvalues of $Ad(r)$ (with multiplicity) are $a_i^{-1}a_j$, where the $a_i$ are the eigenvalues of $r$.  Since $r$ is a reflection (and thus diagonalizable) and $a_i, a_j \in \{1,c\}$, we get that the eigenvalues of $Ad(r)$ are $\{1,c^{-1}, c\}$.

Comment: What's your definition of a reflection? A reflection (across $W \leq V$) to me is an endomorphism with eigen values $\pm 1$, $+1$ on $W$ and $-1$ on some complement (which we could perhaps require an inner product to specify). But yours has some other eigenvalue $c$ instead of $-1$. Is that the only difference?

Comment: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space. A linear map
$g \in GL(V)$ is called a reflection if $g-Id$ has rank one. The determinant of a reflection
is called the special eigenvalue of $g$.